# Can OpenCms be integrated, or used, with an IDE?

Tags: java, opencms

I'm starting with a new project where we'll be using OpenCms. Can the workplace be integrated to an IDE, and which one is it ?

Comment: A good ebook on OpenCms is https://www.packtpub.com/opencms-7-development/book

Answer (score 1):

Also if you are planning to use Eclipse OpenCms module with OpenCms 8, I am afraid you have to use the WebDAV Eclipse plugin with OpenCms, the other plugin stop working.

Link to the [wiki reference page](http://opencms-wiki.org/WebDAV_access_to_the_OpenCms_VFS). 
So once you may set:

- Create a blank new module on your OpenCms.
- Create a standard Java project.
- Change the project setup to create the class files under a folder called "classes" instead of bin.
- Import the module through WebDAV into the new module.
- Create an user library with all the jars placed under the lib/ folder located in the OpenCms deployed war and add it to the buildpath.

Now you are ready to go.

Comment: It's true, by now thats the only decent way we found while having files in SVN, for teamwork, merging, resolving conflicts, etc. But the main problem is that WebDAV in OpenCms doesn't work very well. When you want to export files from project to OpenCms conflict pops up all the time, because of the properties files. You can take a look here for further info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12843994/1005567

Answer (score 0):

If you're just going to develop on your local machine, I'd recommend the [OpenCms Module Developer](http://www.redstardevelopment.nl/opencms/opencms/en/opencms/plugin/) for Eclipse. The only thing you have to be aware of, is setting the encoding of the files to the same (by default Eclipse has some ISO-9... for editors which can be changed in the preferences).
Otherwise you could utilize the webdav-access to the VFS to edit with your favorite Editor.

The [OpenCms Wiki](http://www.opencms-wiki.org/Main_Page) might help as well in general.

Answer (score 0):

This should help if you use Maven (which you can use with Eclipse):

[Fully automated builds with the OpenCms-Maven-Plugin](http://www.opencms-wiki.org/Fully_automated_builds_with_the_OpenCms-Maven-PluginOpenCms.):

> OpenCms-Maven is an open source
>   project ... to ease the build and
>   versioning process of OpenCms
>   projects. The core of the project is a
>   Maven plugin that enables full
>   automated OpenCms builds and provides
>   functionality to synchronize virtual
>   file system resources of OpenCms with
>   a real file system.

Answer (score 0):

here is the link on the wiki that works...
http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/Main_Page