# Opencms webdav not working

Tags: webdav, opencms

With OpenCms 7.5.3 fresh install:

1. I create an index.htm page, then export it via webdav to disk. It
   creates index.html.xml and __properties/index.html.xml.properties.
   Thats ok.
2. Delete index.html from OpenCms and publish.
3. Try to import previously exported files via webdav and...

Error 409 conflict when importing __properties/index.html.xml

I tried with 3 different webdav clients, including the Eclipse plugin for webdav.
Also tried with OpenCms 7.5.4 and 8.5.0

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a known problem by Alkacon (OpenCms developer):

Here is a possible cause:
https://github.com/alkacon/opencms-core/issues/73
("pbeltran" is me there.)

If it helps we did the following on OpenCms 8.5 in order to avoid the error, but sacrificing properties files :(

**Just edit WEB-INF/config/opencms-importexport.xml and replace  with this:**

```
<repository name="standard" class="org.opencms.repository.CmsRepository">
            <params>
                <param name="wrapper">org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsResourceExtensionWrapperJsp</param>
                <param name="wrapper">org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsResourceExtensionWrapperXmlContent</param>
                <param name="wrapper">org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsResourceExtensionWrapperXmlPage</param>
                <param name="wrapper">org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsResourceWrapperSystemFolder</param>
                <!--param name="wrapper">org.opencms.file.wrapper.CmsResourceWrapperPropertyFile</param-->
            </params>
            <filter type="include">
                <regex>/</regex>
                <!--regex>/__properties/.*</regex-->
                <regex>/sites/.*</regex>
                <regex>/system/</regex>
                <!--regex>/system/__properties/.*</regex-->
                <regex>/system/galleries/.*</regex>
                <regex>/system/modules/.*</regex>
                <!--regex>/system/workplace/.*</regex-->
            </filter>
        </repository>
```

Afer that restart your server.

We do regular exports from OpenCms of the modules to keep the whole package (files and properties) in order to keep the solution under control version (SVN). You can create a module with a resource pointing to sites/default to do that. But it's critical to select root site before doing any import/export of that module (if you dont you can break your ocms installation).

Answer (score 1):

I have never had Eclipse with webdav up and running, but I successfully use OpenCms 7.5 and 8 daily with webdav:// and webdavs:// from KDE's Kate editor. Maybe give it a try.

In case you want to try, here the URL you need to use to browse the VFS:

webdav(s)://server(:port)/webdav

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'm sorry but we are working under Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Since some months, I'm using the [Linux FUSE driver](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/davfs2) (gentoo's `davfs 1.4.7`) to mount OpenCms resources. I was quite irritated with the lot of LOG `CmsVfsResourceNotFoundException` errors, so I ended up [removing the `__properties` dirs from the exported Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11765998/413020).

If you don't need these `__properties` files, I'll recommend you to ignore that error and remove the files from the repository as per the instructions in the link.

The corresponding fstab entry:

```
# WebDAV (opencms)
# http://myserver:8080/opencms/webdav /home/alberto/mnt/myserver-opencms-dav davfs rw,user,noauto  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. We precisely need to sync properties files. Also we work under Windows 7. It seems to be a known problem https://github.com/alkacon/opencms-core/issues/73

Comment: @Spekdrum Thanks for your link. I also spent many hours trying to figure out how to fix the problem (the bug you link didn't exist then), instead using this work-around. With the information in the ticket, I think I'll take a look at it again.

Comment: Ok Alberto I'm writing the link as an answer as you said!